# Concatenate with escaped chars in xslt?

Tags: xslt

I'm writing xslt code which concatenates some string:

```
<xsl:attribute name='src'>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('url(&apos;', $imgSrc, '&apos;)')" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

For some reason I can't use it, I keep getting this error:

`Unknown function - Name and number of arguments do not match any function signature in the static context - 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions:concat'`

`while evaluating the expression:
select="concat('url(&apos;', $imgSrc, '&apos;)')"`

Any idea?

thx

====================

## EDIT

I'm trying to get:

```
url('some_path')
```

Was having trouble with the apostrophes, but now it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&apos;` references are resolved by the XML parser that parses your XSLT. Your XSLT processor never sees them. What your XSLT processor sees is:

```
concat('url('', $imgSrc, '')')
```

Which is not valid because the commas don't end up in the right place to separate the arguments. However, this might work for you, [depending on the serializer](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200211/post30020.html) your XSLT processor uses:

```
concat(&quot;url('&quot;, $imgSrc, &quot;')&quot;)
```

This surrounds the arguments in double-quotes, so that your single-quotes do not conflict. The XSLT processor should see this:

```
concat("url('", $imgSrc, "')")
```

Another option is to define a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos" select='"&apos;"'/>
```

Which can be used like this:

```
 concat('url(', $apos, $imgSrc, $apos, ')')
```

More [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/03/14/trxml10.html):

> When you apply an XSLT stylesheet to a
>   document, if entities are declared and
>   referenced in that document, your XSLT
>   processor won't even know about them.
>   An XSLT processor leaves the job of
>   parsing the input document (reading it
>   and figuring out what's what) to an
>   XML parser; that's why the
>   installation of some XSLT processors
>   requires you to identify the XML
>   parser you want them to use. (Others
>   include an XML parser as part of their
>   installation.) An important part of an
>   XML parser's job is to resolve all
>   entity references, so that if the
>   input document's DTD declares a cpdate
>   entity as having the value "2001" and
>   the document has the line "copyright
>   &cpdate; all rights reserved", the XML
>   parser will pass along the text node
>   "copyright 2001 all rights reserved"
>   to put on the XSLT source tree.

Comment: Isn't this an argument? ->'url(&apos;' I thought it would convert to "url('"

Comment: My eyeballs parsed that wrong the first time. See my updated answer.

Comment: @lwburk: Only `<xsl:value-of select="concat(&quot;url('&quot;, $imgSrc, &quot;')&quot;)"/>` would be right because of [Attribute Value Normalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#AVNormalize), meaning that you would expect that the XPath expression **must be embbed in an XML document**. Check my answer for a detail explanation of the problem.

Comment: @Alejandro - I see your point. Nonetheless, both solutions do in fact work in Firefox, at the very least, which is where I tested.

Comment: @lwburk: Yes. Your variable definition also depends on Attribute Value Normalization. For an XSLT solution I would say it's fine: XSLT stylesheet is an XML document. But you are not addressing the problem: XPath string literal constraint.

Comment: My preference is to use variables, and to declare them as `<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>` to avoid the reader experiencing eyeball-strain.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-Literal

```
[29]    Literal    ::=    '"' [^"]* '"'  |  "'" [^']* "'"
```

Meaning that an XPath literal string value can't have the delimiter as also part of the content.

For this you should use the host language. In XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="$vPrefix">url('</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="$vSufix">')</xsl:variable>
<xsl:attribute name="src">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat($vPrefix, $imgSrc, $vSufix)" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

Or more proper:

```
<xsl:attribute name="src">
     <xsl:text>url('</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="$imgSrc"/>
     <xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
```